# golang deepEqual interface{} to integer

Tags: go, redis

I'm using the `redigo` redis library, and checking if a key is already present in a `redis set`. I'm using the redis command `SISMEMBER` via the redigo's `Do` method which returns an interface. It is the response of the command being executed using `Do`. In case of `SISMEMBER` command, the response in a `1` or `0`. and in this particular case, the response is `0` as the given key is not present in this set. however `reflect.DeepEqual(resp, 0)` is returning `false` when `true` is expected. Is this not the correct way to use `DeepEqual` function?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:6379")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    resp, err := conn.Do("SISMEMBER", "mySet", "Hello")
    if reflect.DeepEqual(resp, 0) {
        fmt.Println("record doesn't exist")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of over complicate your code, you can use some build-in functions of redigo to convert the response to `int` and afterward check if the key is or is not in redis.

```
resp, err := redis.Int(conn.Do("SISMEMBER", "mySet", "Hello"))
if err != nil {
    // some error handler
}
if resp == 0 {
    fmt.Println("record doesn't exist")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fmt.Printf("ret type: %T, ret: %v\n", resp, resp)
```

when I did check the type of the `resp` interface, i found that it is `int64`, so casting the `0` appropriately, like below, helped.

```
reflect.DeepEqual(resp, int64(0))
```